# C# Is there anyway of getting the value of a contain statement

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this

```
String[] greet = "hi","hello","hey";
String match;
String sen = "hi, how are you?";
if(sen.contains(greet[]))
{
       //get the "hi" from the sen.
       Match = //the matching words           
}
```

I have to find a way of getting the word that the contain statement matched.

Answer (score 3):

Use linq's `.Where` to get the collection of words matching:

```
string[] greet = new string[] { "hi", "hello", "hey" };
string sen = "hi, how are you?";

List<string> matches = greet.Where(w => sen.Contains(w)).ToList();
```

- [`string.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) checks if a given string is contained in another. If you want a case insensitive search: [Case insensitive 'Contains(string)'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/444798/6400526)
- [`IEnumerable<T>.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a subset of the collection containing only the items matching the predicate - in this case only those that were found in the `sen`

Comment: It give me this "System.Collection.Generic.List'1[System.String] how should i fix this

Comment: @JLProduction - you cannot use `ToString` on it - it is not a single string but a collection of strings. If you want to access for instance the first item in the collection you can do it with the indexer operator: `matches[0]` which will give you a single string

Comment: @JLProduction - did you understand how to use this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably easier to use a `foreach` statement and loop through greet, and then split up sen by white space (ie. `""`) so you have two arrays. Then you can just check to see if your values match.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to *split* the sentence into *words* (let's decribe word as a nonempty sequence of letters or/and apostrophes - `[\w']+`):

```
  String sen = "hi, how are you?";

  // ["hi", "how", "are", "you"]
  String[] words = Regex
    .Matches(sen, @"[\w']+")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

And then filter out all words that are in `Greet`:

```
  HashSet<string> greet = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { 
    "hi", "hello", "hey" };

  List<string> matches = words
    .Where(word => greet.Contains(word))
    .ToList();
```

Or if we combine both parts:

```
  HashSet<string> greet = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { 
    "hi", "hello", "hey" };

  List<string> matches = Regex
    .Matches(sen, @"[\w']+")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value)
    .Where(word => greet.Contains(word))
    .ToList();
```

Please, nocice that `HashSet<T>` is often more convenient than `T[]` when we want to perform `Contain`.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> greet = new List<string>(){ "hi", "hello", "hey" };
List<string> matches;
string sentence = "hi, how are you?";
matches = greet.FindAll(g => sentence.Contains(g));
foreach (var match in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(match);
```